# Infinite decent and inifinity

Tags: logic, induction, real-numbers, infinity

I have a question regarding the validity of infinity in the logic of math.

If we can define logically a number by it's infinite sum (as a limit of series ...etc) than how can it be logic to use the infinite decent as a proof for non existence of solution (like in Fermat proof for degree 3.

If is it OK to consider the infinite limit as a contradiction than how can we accept the  irrational numbers as an infinite decimal expansion.
I hope I was clear in my question at least...

Comment: Do you accept *mathematical induction* as a valid proof technique? Because *infinite decent* is logically the same, just expressed in other words.

Comment: Yes in some case it can be expressed as induction  in other words, but could we say that it can always be inverted into induction proof.

Comment: Yes, it can *always* be written as a proof by induction. As Stefan's answer explains, it is all about well-orders. Unfortunately I do not get what these proof techniques have to do with limits of sequences. These are two completely different use-cases for "infinities".

Comment: This depends on how you define *mathematical induction*. If you define it in its general form, allowing any well-order instead of only $(\mathbb N; <)$, then they are indeed equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is behind any 'infinite descent' argument is a so-called *[well-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)*.

The poster child of an infinite well-order is $(\mathbb N; <)$, i.e. the set of natural numbers with their natural order. The key aspect of a well-order $(X; \prec)$ is that there are no infinite decreasing sequences, i.e. there is no sequence $(x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$

- $x_n \in X$ and
- $x_{n+1} \prec x_n$.

If you can show that a certain order is a well-order and that the contrapositive of your claim yields an infinite decreasing sequence in said order, you derive the desired contradiction. This sort of argument is sometimes called 'proof by infinite descent'. (Which, in my opinion, is a poor choice of words.)

Comment: As you see, this argument doesn't really have to do anything with the abstract concept of 'infinity' or 'limits'. Rather it's a simple observation about certain relations that can be exploited.